# Change Google Analytics report api language

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I am working with [Google Analytics report api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)

I want to know if API support lang change.
I've googled, but no information had been founded.

I want to make sure there is no language change support, before translating it myself.
I am creating UI, which supports "Korean".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the underlying language returned by a Google api.  These are designed in English and the data is often stored in English as well unless they are strict strings submitted by a user in another language.

These string you will need to translate locally yourself.

You may want to consider sending a feature request [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400).  While i doubt they would consider adding anything to the reporting api at this time since it will be discontinued in a year or so.   Its worth bringing it up to them maybe they will add it to the data api for GA4